# Confusing Light Switch Wiring

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, multiway-switch

I have a panel with two light switches in my house. The switch on the right controls the porch light outside the door to the left, and the left switch… does not seem to do anything at all. Before we moved in a couple years back, I tested all the outlets and lights in the room and outside, but nothing changes.

I’m getting ready to replace all the light switches in our house, and I decided to figure out what this switch does, so I pulled it out and discovered it’s actually a three-way switch! I went around and tested all the switches again just to make sure, but it definitely does nothing.

There is a bedroom behind the wall these switches are on we suspected originally opened up to the first room, so I took a look at the light switch in that room (which also does nothing) and discovered it’s not even wired at all! The three wires are just taped up separately in there. The light in this room is unaffected by the switches in the other room, and works fine with its pull chains, which is honestly a little bit confusing to me.

My ideal solution here would be to wire this so that the light switch in the bedroom is functional, and splice the wires in the other room to accommodate this without the need for there to be a second switch there.

[image: Photo of Wiring]
[image: Drawing of Wiring]

Since it’s a bit difficult to describe how things are wired through text, I’m attaching a quick drawing and photo of how it looks now. The blue boxes are the switches (upside down), cable 1 I think is probably coming from the breaker, cable 2 to the porch light, then 3 and 4 have to be the bedroom light and switch, but I’m not too sure which would be which.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you checked for switched receptacles?

Comment: Yes, I've checked all the receptacles inside and on the porch, and none of them are affected by this switch.

Comment: Code says a room must have a light switch near the door that works a light(ceiling or outlet).   Not everyone reads code.   Possible someone put in light with pull switches and figure wall switch was not needed.

Comment: To me it looks like 4 way switch not 3 way

Comment: What do you have for diagnostic tools? Multimeter, voltage tester, or anything like that? Pictures of the switch box with the disconnected switch and the light fixture junction box of the light you want it to control would be helpful as well. I'm suspecting your guesses, but the point is not to make more guesses, but to sort out really what's connected to what where. And that starts by looking at what those other boxes have for cables and connections.